# How implement PostgreSQL extension using PostGIS types

Tags: c, postgresql, postgis

I would like to create a new data type for PostGIS, but I have some difficulties. Here's what I've done so far:

```
/* PostgreSQL */
#include <postgres.h>
#include <liblwgeom.h>
#include <lwgeom_pg.h>
#include <utils/timestamp.h>


struct trajectory_elem
{
  // int32 dummy;    /* Padding to make it double aligned. */
  Timestamp time_obj;
  LWGEOM *geom_elem;       /* Geometry Object - */
};

#define DatumGetTrajectoryElem(X)      ((struct trajectory_elem*) PG_DETOAST_DATUM(X))
#define PG_GETARG_TRAJECTELEM_TYPE_P(n)  DatumGetTrajectoryElem(PG_GETARG_DATUM(n))
#define PG_RETURN_TRAJECTELEM_TYPE_P(x)  PG_RETURN_POINTER(x)


extern Datum create_trajectory_elem(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);
extern Datum trajectory_elem_in(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);
extern Datum trajectory_elem_out(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);

.....
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(create_trajectory_elem);

Datum
create_trajectory_elem(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
 {
   Timestamp time_geom = PG_GETARG_TIMESTAMP(0);
   GSERIALIZED *geom = (GSERIALIZED*)PG_DETOAST_DATUM(PG_GETARG_DATUM(1));

   struct trajectory_elem *trje = (struct trajectory_elem *) palloc(sizeof(struct trajectory_elem));

   trje->time_obj = time_geom;

   /*get lwgeom from GSERIALIZED varlena*/
   trje->geom_elem = lwgeom_from_gserialized(geom);

   if ( lwgeom_is_empty(trje->geom_elem))
   {
     PG_FREE_IF_COPY(geom, 0);
     PG_RETURN_NULL();
   }

   PG_FREE_IF_COPY(geom, 0);

   PG_RETURN_TRAJECTELEM_TYPE_P(trje);

 }
```

Is the way I'm creating my trajectory_elem structure correct?

Can I simply point to the LWGEO type? Or.. Should I create a new type like the GSERIALIZED ?

How would the input and output functions for this type be? Could I use the functions already implemented by PostGIS?

I tested some implementations for the I / O functions but when it arrives in PG_RETURN_TRAJECTELEM_TYPE_P (create_trajectory_elem), the server drops. So they were probably wrong

Comment: rather than creating your own type, why not use a LINESTRING of 4d points? where 4d = time? that's what everyone else does? Really, if you want to go down this route though you're better of seeking help on [dba.se] or [gis.se]

Comment: The type will not just be that. This is only a part..

Comment: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/DevWikiPostGISCoding